# Finding length of median

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the given figure ABCD and MNPD are square ,AB=a and NP=b then find QT if AT=TP

IS the above question correct? I tried solving it a lot but could not solve

Comment: Hint: What is $\angle AQP$? (What are the slopes of $\overline{AQ}$ and $\overline{PQ}$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In triangle AMD where AD=a and MD=b and let AP represent x axis Hence slop of AM is $m_{AM}=\frac{b}{a}$ and similarly since CD=a and DP=b Hence slope of PC is $m_{PC}=-\frac{a}{b}$
$$. $$
Hence AQP is right angle triangle and T is circumcenter of triangle
Hence AT=PT=QT=$\frac{a+b}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(0,0)$ and $D(a,0)$. Hence, $P(a+b,0)$, $M(a,b)$, $C(a,a)$, $T\left(\frac{a+b}{2},0\right)$.

Equation of $PQ$ is 
$$y-a=-\frac{a}{b}(x-a) \tag{1}$$
therefore 
$$y=-\frac{a}{b}x+\frac{a^2+b^2}{b} \tag{2}$$
Also equation of $AQ$ is 
$$y=\frac{b}{a}x \tag{3}$$

Solving $(2)$ and $(3)$: 
$$Q\left(\frac{a^2(a+b)}{a^2+b^2},\frac{ab(a+b)}{a^2+b^2}\right) \tag{4}$$
Hence, 
$$QT=\frac{a+b}{2} \tag{5}$$

Comment: Thanks for correction now I think it is correct.